# MySQL Show counts without subquery

Tags: mysql, large-data

I have following table

| Id | source_url | target_url | event_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | googlecom | mypageurl/example | 0 |
| 2 | googlecom | mypageurl/otherpage | 0 |
| 3 | googlecom | mypageurl/example | 0 |
| 4 | googlecom | mypageurl/example | 0 |
| 5 | mypageurl/example | otherdomain/example | 1 |
| 6 | mypageurl/example | otherdomain/example | 1 |
| 7 | mypageurl/otherpage | otherdomain/example | 1 |

Here `event_type = 0` is Visit and `event_type = 1` is Click

Using following query I can get **visits** on each url

```
SELECT
    target_url,
    COUNT(target_url) AS visits
FROM
    tbl_events
WHERE
    event_type = 0 AND target_url <> ''
GROUP BY
    target_url
ORDER BY
    visits
DESC
    ;
```

#### Visits

| target_url | visits |
| --- | --- |
| mypageurl/example | 3 |
| mypageurl/otherpage | 1 |

And with following query i can get clicks

```
SELECT
    source_url,
    COUNT(source_url) AS clicks
FROM
    event_tracking
WHERE
    event_type = 1 AND source_url <> ''
GROUP BY
    source_url
ORDER BY
    clicks
DESC
    ;
```

#### Clicks

| source_url | clicks |
| --- | --- |
| mypageurl/example | 2 |
| mypageurl/otherpage | 1 |

#### Desired Result

I want my final result to be like below ***without using subquery*** (since original table contains more than 1 million rows and subquery takes too long)

| url | clicks | visits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mypageurl/example | 2 | 3 |
| mypageurl/otherpage | 1 | 1 |

Right now, I feel like I have to create a temporary table and use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and use url as primary key, but I feel like there might be a better way and I couldn't figure out.

Is there any way to achieve this result without using subquery and temporary table?

Comment: This is pivot. Use conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT URL, 
       SUM(click) click, 
       SUM(VISIT) visit 
FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN event_type=0 
                  THEN target_url 
                  ELSE source_url END      url, 
             SUM(CASE WHEN event_type = 0 
                      THEN 1 
                      ELSE 0 END)          visit, 
             SUM(CASE WHEN event_type = 1 
                      THEN 1 
                      ELSE 0 END)          click
      FROM urlData
      GROUP BY target_url, 
               source_url,
               event_type  ) A 
GROUP BY URL
```